# Drower in react native does not activate until reload app

Tags: react-native

Good morning. I have the following doubt, I have this personal project, but I am facing a problem that I have not been able to solve, I have implemented a drower, which works fine, until I reload the application, that is where the drower no longer works until which I reload my context.js file,
I have tried to execute a function from context in App.js hoping that it will be activated when loading the app file. js, without success, I will leave the code hoping that someone has already faced this problem and guides me what to do because I can't anymore, I have no idea how to do it.

```js
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import MaterialCommunityIcons from "react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons";
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import * as eva from "@eva-design/eva";
import {
  ApplicationProvider,
  Layout,
  IconRegistry,
  Button,
  Icon,
} from "@ui-kitten/components";
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { EvaIconsPack } from "@ui-kitten/eva-icons";
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import { default as mapping } from "./mapping.json";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
import HomeScreen from "./components/HomeScreen";
import Products from "./components/Products";
import Offert from "./components/Offert";
import Favorites from "./components/Favorites";
import MyAccount from "./components/MyAccount";
import ModalBimbo from "./modalScreen/Bimbo";
import Login from "./components/Login";
import UpdateUser from "./modalScreen/UpdateUser";
import { Register } from "./modalScreen/Register";
import { StateProvider, useMyContext } from "./appContext/appContext";
import { useFonts } from "expo-font";
import { Loading } from "./components/Loading";
import { RenderProducts } from "./components/RenderProducts";
import { Title } from "react-native-paper";
import { Logout } from "./utils/helpers";
import { ContextApp } from "./appContext/appContext";

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function MyTabs({ navigation }) {
  const {getProveedores} = ContextApp()

  useEffect(()=>{
    console.log("2")
    getProveedores()
  },[])

  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Tiendita de la Esquina"
        component={HomeScreen}
        options={{
          headerShown: false,
          tabBarLabel: "Home",
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="home" color={color} size={30} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Productos"
        component={Products}
        options={{
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "red",
          },
          headerTintColor: "#fff",
          headerTitleStyle: {
            fontWeight: "bold",
          },
          tabBarLabel: "Productos",
          tabBarActiveTintColor: "gray",
          tabBarStyle: { backgroundColor: "white" },
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons
              name="shopping-search"
              color={color}
              size={30}
            />
          ),
        }}
      />

      <Tab.Screen
        name="Ofertas"
        component={Offert}
        options={{
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "red",
          },
          headerTintColor: "#fff",
          headerTitleStyle: {
            fontWeight: "bold",
          },
          tabBarLabel: "Productos",
          tabBarActiveTintColor: "gray",
          tabBarStyle: { backgroundColor: "white" },
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="tag" color={color} size={30} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Favoritos"
        component={Favorites}
        options={{
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "red",
          },
          headerTintColor: "#fff",
          headerTitleStyle: {
            fontWeight: "bold",
          },
          tabBarLabel: "Productos",
          tabBarActiveTintColor: "gray",
          tabBarStyle: { backgroundColor: "white" },
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="heart" color={color} size={30} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Mi Cuenta"
        component={MyAccount}
        options={({ navigation }) => ({
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "red",
          },
          headerTintColor: "#fff",
          headerTitleStyle: {
            fontWeight: "bold",
          },
          tabBarLabel: "Mi Cuenta",
          tabBarActiveTintColor: "gray",
          tabBarStyle: { backgroundColor: "white" },
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="account" color={color} size={30} />
            ),
            headerRight: () => <IconRender />,
        })}
      />
    
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

const IconLogout = (props) => (
  <MaterialCommunityIcons name="power" color={props.color} size={20}/>
)


export function DrawerStackScreen() {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator 
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown:  false
      }}  
    >
      <Drawer.Screen name="MyTabs" component={MyTabs} />
      <Drawer.Screen 
       name="Cerrar Sesion"
       component={Logout}
        options={{
          headerShown: false,
          drawerIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => <IconLogout color="red"/>,
        }}
       />
      
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
  
}

export default function App() {
  const [fontLoaded] = useFonts({
    Bela: require("./assets/fonts/Belanosima-SemiBold.ttf"),
    BelaRegular: require("./assets/fonts/Belanosima-Regular.ttf"),
    Poppins: require("./assets/fonts/Poppins-Light.ttf"),
  });
  if (!fontLoaded) return null;
  return (
    <StateProvider MyTabs={MyTabs}>
      <>
        <IconRegistry icons={EvaIconsPack} />
        <ApplicationProvider {...eva} theme={eva.light} customMapping={mapping}>
          <NavigationContainer style={styles.container}>
            <Stack.Navigator>
              <Stack.Screen
               name="DrawerStack" // Puedes darle el nombre que desees
               component={DrawerStackScreen}
               options={{ headerShown: false }}
              />
              <Stack.Screen
               name="Loading"
               component={Loading}
               options={{ headerShown: false }}
              />
              <Stack.Screen
               name="MyTabs"
               component={MyTabs}
               options={{ headerShown: false }}
              />
              <Stack.Screen
               name="RenderProducts"
               component={RenderProducts}
               options={{ headerShown: false }}
              />
              <Stack.Screen
                name="Login"
                component={Login}
                options={({ navigation }) => ({
                  title: "  Bienvenido",
                  headerStyle: {
                    backgroundColor: "red",
                  },
                  headerTintColor: "#fff",
                  headerTitleStyle: {
                    fontWeight: "bold",
                  },
                  headerLeft: () => (
                    <Icon
                      style={styles.icon}
                      fill="#fff"
                      name="arrow-back-outline"
                      onPress={() => {
                        navigation.navigate("MyTabs");
                      }}
                    />
                  ),
                })}
              />
              <Stack.Screen
                name="HomeScreen"
                component={HomeScreen}
                options={{ headerShown: false }}
              />

              <Stack.Screen
                name="Register"
                component={Register}
                options={({ navigation }) => ({
                  title: "Registro",
                  headerStyle: {
                    backgroundColor: "red",
                  },
                  headerTintColor: "#fff",
                  headerTitleStyle: {
                    fontWeight: "bold",
                  },
                  headerLeft: () => (
                    <Icon
                      style={styles.icon}
                      fill="#fff"
                      name="arrow-back-outline"
                      onPress={() => {
                        navigation.navigate("MyTabs");
                      }}
                    />
                  ),
                })}
              />
              <Stack.Screen
                name="ModalBimbo"
                component={ModalBimbo}
                options={({ navigation }) => ({
                  title: "Bimbo",
                  headerStyle: {
                    backgroundColor: "red",
                  },
                  headerTintColor: "#fff",
                  headerTitleStyle: {
                    fontWeight: "bold",
                  },
                  headerLeft: () => (
                    <Icon
                      style={styles.icon}
                      fill="#fff"
                      name="arrow-back-outline"
                      onPress={() => {
                        navigation.navigate("MyTabs");
                      }}
                    />
                  ),
                })}
                />
              <Stack.Screen
                name="UpdateUser"
                component={UpdateUser}
                options={({ navigation }) => ({
                  title: "Actualizar Datos",
                  headerStyle: {
                    backgroundColor: "red",
                  },
                  headerTintColor: "#fff",
                  headerTitleStyle: {
                    fontWeight: "bold",
                  },
                  headerLeft: () => (
                    <Icon
                      style={styles.icon}
                      fill="#fff"
                      name="arrow-back-outline"
                      onPress={() => {
                        navigation.navigate("MyTabs");
                      }}
                    />
                  ),
                })}
              ></Stack.Screen>
            </Stack.Navigator>
            <StatusBar style="auto" />
          </NavigationContainer>
        </ApplicationProvider>
      </>
    </StateProvider>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  icon: {
    width: 32,
    height: 32,
  },
});
```

```html
import React, { createContext, useState, useContext, useEffect } from 'react';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import axios from 'axios';
//import { API_URL} from '@env';

export const useMyContext = () => useContext(StateContext);
export const StateContext = createContext(null);

//Por si quieres usar una funcion en app ya que no puedes importar
//funciones desde context en App.js
export const ContextApp = () => {
  return useMyContext();
};


export const StateProvider = ({ children }) => {
  
 const [user, setUser] = useState('');
 const [password, setpassword] = useState('')
 const [token,setToken] = useState('')
 const [uid, setUid] = useState()
 const [imagen, setImagen] = useState({})
 const [productos, setProductos] = useState({})
 const [name, setName] = useState("")

  const login =  () => {
    return axios.post('https://abarrotes.msalazar.dev/user/login?_format=json', {
    "name": user,
    "pass": password,
      headers : {
      "Content-Type" : "application/json",
      },
    })
    .then(async function (response) {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem("@UID",response.data.current_user.uid)
      return response.status
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error, "error de logueo")
    });

  }

  const getToken = () => {
     return axios.post('https://abarrotes.msalazar.dev/session/token?_format=json', {
      headers : {
        "Content-Type" : "application/json",
      },
    }).then( async res=>{
        console.log(res.data)
        return res.data
    }).catch(err=>{
      console.log(err)
    })
  }

  const getUid = async () => {
   const uidUser = await AsyncStorage.getItem("@UID")
   getDataUser(uidUser)
  }

  const userRemove= async()=> {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.removeItem("@name")
      console.log("user eliminado")
    } catch(error) {
      console.log(error, "error en el catech")
    }
  }

  const tokenDelete=async()=> {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.removeItem("@token")
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  } 

  const getProveedores = () => {
    axios.get('https://abarrotes.msalazar.dev/jsonapi/node/img_proveedores?include=field_img_proveedores', {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    })
    .then(function (response) {
      setImagen(response.data)
      setProductos(response.data.data)
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });  
  }

  const getDataUser = async (uid)=> {
    await axios.get(`https://abarrotes.msalazar.dev/user/` + uid + `?_format=json`, {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type" : "application/json",
      },
    }).then(async(response) =>{
       //console.log(response.data)
      //setUidStorage(response.data.uid[0].value)
      //setApellidoUser(response.data.field_apellidos_usuario[0].value)
      //setDireccionUser(response.data.field_direccion_usuario[0].value)
      //setTelefonoUser(response.data.field_telefono_usuario[0].value)
      //setEmailUser(response.data.field_email_usuario[0].value)
      await AsyncStorage.setItem("@name", response.data.field_nombre_usuario[0].value) 
      const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@name');
      console.log(value, "name" )
      if(value !== null) {
        setName(value)
      }
      // await AsyncStorage.setItem("@lastname", response.data.field_apellidos_usuario[0].value)
      // await AsyncStorage.setItem("@address", response.data.field_direccion_usuario[0].value)
      // await AsyncStorage.setItem("@email", response.data.field_email_usuario[0].value)
      // await AsyncStorage.setItem("@phone", response.data.field_telefono_usuario[0].value)
    })
  }
  useEffect(()=>{
   getProveedores()
   getUid()
   console.log("1")
   
  },[])

  return (
    <StateContext.Provider value={{
     setToken,
     setUser,
     setpassword,
     tokenDelete,
     userRemove,
     login,
     getToken,
     getProveedores,
     getUid,
     user,
     password,
     imagen,
     productos,
     name,
     
    }}>
      {children}
    </StateContext.Provider>
  );
};
```